Выборка записей из many-to-many таблицы (PostgreSQL)
Коллеги, дайте ума, пожалуйста.
Проще всего будет объяснить на примере "повареной книги". Есть рецепты и есть ингредиенты. Many-to-many табличка выглядит примерно так:
-------------------------
|  recipes_ingredients  |
-------------------------
recipe_id | ingredient_id
-------------------------
r_id_1    | i_id_1
r_id_1    | i_id_2
r_id_2    | i_id_3
r_id_2    | i_id_2
r_id_2    | i_id_4
r_id_3    | i_id_1
r_id_3    | i_id_2

Пользователь хочет выбрать все рецепты, которые содержат только ингредиенты i_id_1 И i_id_2. Эти продукты могут содержаться и в других рецептах, но поскольку в этих других рецептах содержатся и другие продукты, которых у пользователя нет, то в результат должны попасть 2 рецепта с r_id_1 и r_id_3. Я пробовал выборки с any и all, вроде такой:
select * from recipes_ingredients
where ingredient_id = any('{i_id_1, i_id_2}');

но очевидно, что в таком варианте выбирается И рецепт с r_id_2.
Пытался как-то подзапросами решить, но стало очевидно, что знаний и опыта не хватает, да и пример запроса по памяти уже не приведу. В общем, буду благодарен за вашу помощь!

Обычное логическое деление. В общем случае можно как-то так:
SELECT recipe_id 
FROM recipes_ingredients
GROUP BY recipe_id 
HAVING SUM((ingredient_id IN ( i_id_1, i_id_2 )) :: INT ) = 2
   AND SUM((ingredient_id NOT IN ( i_id_1, i_id_2 )) :: INT ) = 0


Кажется, это то, что нужно! Вот эта конструкция для меня не знакома, буду изучать! SUM((ingredient_id IN ( i_id_1, i_id_2 )) :: INT ) = 2. Большое спасибо!

@AlexSazonov Так всё элементарно. Проверка (IN) даёт TRUE, FALSE или NULL. Преобразование в целое (INT) даёт соответственно 1, 0 или NULL. SUM() отбрасывает NULL и возвращает сумму - т.е. количество единиц, т.е. количество TRUE.
